# Regular Expression for UpperCase Letters In A String

Tags: java, regex

For the life of me, I can't figure out why this regular expression is not working. It should find upper case letters in the given string and give me the count. Any ideas are welcome.

Here is the unit test code:

```
public class RegEx {

    @Test
    public void testCountTheNumberOfUpperCaseCharacters() {
        String testStr = "abcdefghijkTYYtyyQ";
        String regEx = "^[A-Z]+$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);

        System.out.printf("Found %d, of capital letters in %s%n", matcher.groupCount(), testStr);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You didn't call `matches` or `find` on the matcher. It hasn't done any work.
2. `getGroupCount` is the wrong method to call. Your regex has no capture groups, and even if it did, it wouldn't give you the character count.

You should be using `find`, but with a different regex, one without anchors. I would also advise using the proper Unicode character class: `"\\p{Lu}+"`. Use this in a `while (m.find())` loop, and accumulate the total number of characters obtained from `m.group(0).length()` at each step.

Comment: Mentioning `"\\p{Lu}+"` is the key part for me here. I've started a bounty before seeing this part of your answer and I have the other answer in mind, but at the very least I'm upvoting your answer.

Answer (score 20):

It doesn't work because you have 2 problems:

1. Regex is incorrect, it should be `"[A-Z]"` for ASCII letter or `\p{Lu}` for Unicode uppercase letters
2. You're not calling `while (matcher.find())` before `matcher.groupCount()`

**Correct code:**

```
public void testCountTheNumberOfUpperCaseCharacters() {
    String testStr = "abcdefghijkTYYtyyQ";
    String regEx = "(\\p{Lu})";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);
    while (matcher.find())
        System.out.printf("Found %d, of capital letters in %s%n", 
          matcher.groupCount(), testStr);

}
```

UPDATE: Use this **much simpler one-liner code** to count number of Unicode upper case letters in a string:

```
int countuc = testStr.split("(?=\\p{Lu})").length - 1;
```

Comment: `groupCount` doesn't count the characters. The anwer will be always the same.

Comment: I didn't claim that it counts characters. Let me edit it anyway to answer that part also.

Comment: OP is counting characters, therefore with "**correct code**" you have implied that your solution counts characters.

Comment: I have provided a simpler code for counting upper case letters in my last edit.

Comment: @anubhava : I tried submitting an edit, but SO won't allow a tiny, 1-character edit:  you should remove the `+` in your description (#1 on your 2-item list), to match your code

Answer (score 6):

This should do what you're after,

```
@Test
public void testCountTheNumberOfUpperCaseCharacters() {
  String testStr = "abcdefghijkTYYtyyQ";
  String regEx = "[A-Z]+";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);
  int count = 0;
  while (matcher.find()) {
    count+=matcher.group(0).length();
  }
  System.out.printf("Found %d, of capital letters in %s%n", count, testStr);
}
```

Comment: You would (probably) speed it up by using `[A-Z]+` and `count += matcher.group(0).length()`.

Answer (score 3):

> It should find upper case letters in the given string and give me the count.

No, it shouldn't: the `^` and `$` anchors prevent it from doing so, forcing to look for a non-empty string composed *entirely* of uppercase characters.

Moreover, you cannot expect a group count in an expression that does not define groups to be anything other than zero (no matches) or one (a single match).

If you insist on using a regex, use a simple `[A-Z]` expression with no anchors, and call `matcher.find()` in a loop. A better approach, however, would be calling [`Character.isUpperCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29) on the characters of your string, and counting the hits:

```
int count = 0;
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one gives better performance either Regex solution or yours? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @MaheshVarma I did not benchmark it, but my solution should be considerably faster.

Comment: This, big time. `[A-Z]` does not match `Č`, which in my opinion (coming from the central Europe) is quite a big deal ;) `Character.isUpperCase("Č")` correctly reports `true` on the other hand.

Comment: @vektor If you had tried to search about *matching upper case letters in any language + regex* thousands of questions and answers would have got your attention.

Comment: @revo possible, but I found this one when searching for "keep only uppercase letters in a string" or something similar and while it seems to be talking about the general case, it will only work for ASCII. Thus my attempt to highlight this aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern as you've written it looks for 1 or more capital letters between the beginning and the end of the line...if there are any lowercase characters in the line it won't match.

Answer (score 0):

In this example i'm using a regex(regular Expression) to count the number of UpperCase and LowerCase letters in the given string using Java.

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class CandidateCode {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    //  Reads the String of data entered in a line
        String str = sc.nextLine();

    //counts uppercase letteres in the given String 
        int countuc = str.split("([A-Z]+?)").length; 

    //counts lowercase letteres in the given String 
        int countlc = str.split("([a-z]+?)").length; 

        System.out.println("UpperCase count: "+countuc-1);
        System.out.println("LowerCase count: "+countlc-1);
   }
}
```

Comment: don't put just a code, add some description regarding your answer,

Comment: Thank you for your comments ankit, I've added a few details about the code ,hope it would be useful in understanding the code

Answer (score 0):

Change the regular expression to 
**[A-Z]** which checks all occurrences of capital letters

Please refer the below example which counts number of capital letters in a string using pattern

```
@Test
public void testCountTheNumberOfUpperCaseCharacters() {
    Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]");
    Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher("ivekKVVV");
    int from = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while(matcher.find(from)) {
        count++;
        from = matcher.start() + 1;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Java Regex, for example:

```
.+[\p{javaUpperCase}].+
```

An example from my work project:
[image: RegEx Result Image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for Java 9 and later that makes use of the [results() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--) of Matcher, which returns a stream of the results, out of which the entries can be counted. The suggestion from @Sergey Kalinichenko to remove the `^` and `$` anchors has also been incorporated into the regex string.

```
public class RegEx {
 @Test
 public void testCountTheNumberOfUpperCaseCharacters() {
    String testStr = "abcdefghijkTYYtyyQ";
    String regEx = "\\p{Lu}";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(testStr);
    long count = matcher.results().count();
    
    System.out.printf("Found %d of capital letters in %s%n", count, testStr);

 }
}
```