# Count uppercase letters in a string

Tags: java, string, char

I am trying to create a simple program that counts the uppercase characters in a `String` by looping through each character and incrementing an accumulator variable if the character is uppercase. Here is my code:

```
String str = "JuSTin"; //3 uppercase characters
int upperCaseCount = 0; //increment each time an uppercase character is encountered
char character; //the current character
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
{
  character = str.charAt(i);
  System.out.println(character); //Log all characters to console just to see what is going on
  if(Character.isUpperCase(character))
      upperCaseCount++; 
  i++;  
}
System.out.println("Uppercase characters: " + upperCaseCount);
```

When ran this code outputs:

```
J
S
i
Uppercase characters: 2
```

What is causing this output? Where is the 'u' 'T' and 'n' in "JuSTin"? Why is `upperCaseCount` equal to 2 and not 3?

Comment: You're doing `i++` twice. That's causing letters to be skipped. This appears to be a typo.

Comment: This is the most foolish i've felt on this site... thank you. Should I close the question?

Comment: I voted to close it as a typo, but now that's there's answers, you won't be able to delete it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as a complement information (for your learning-purpose), you can solve it in different ways using:

- lambda,
- 'classic' for loop,
- loop construct introduced in Java 7,
- regular expression,
- or forEach loop

Each of these ways have their own advantages or drawbacks.

**With a lambda**

```
public static long countUpperCase(final String str) {
        return str
                .chars() // get all chars from the argument
                .filter(c -> Character.isUpperCase(c)) // filter only the uppercase
                .count(); // count the uppercase
    }
```

**With a classic for loop**

```
public static long countUpperCase(final String str) {
    long counter = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(i))) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

**With new loop construct (Java 7 or higher)**

```
public static long countUpperCase(final String str) {
    long counter = 0;

    for(final char c: str.toCharArray()) {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

There are already some explanation in other posts, e.g. [Uppercase SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20661724/regular-expression-for-uppercase-letters-in-a-string)

**With a regular expression**

```
public static long countUpperCase(final String str) {
    // \p{L} matches a single code point in the category "letter"
    // \p{L} matches all letters that are uppercase
    return str.split("(?=\\p{Lu})").length;
}
```

If you are interesting to dig a bit deeper, have a look at this interesting PDF: [Guide to Regexp](https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/regexp_mcp_ess.pdf)

**With a forEach loop**

```
public static long countUpperCase(final String str) {
    // the 'var' keyword can be used with Java 10 or higher
    final var counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    // convert a string into a List<Character>
    // Note that this is only applicable since Java 8 or higher
    var chars = str
            .chars()
            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // count the number of uppercase letters
    chars.forEach(c -> {
        if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
            counter.incrementAndGet();
        }
    });

    return counter.get();
}
```

Comment: Above and beyond and very insightful! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the second `i++`. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you incrementing i++ inside if condition. The value of i will automatically increment using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

In `for` loop `for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)` you are already incrementing the value of `i` using `i++` but you have put `i++` inside the `for` loop again.So the value of `i` will be incremented twice. That's why you are getting wrong output. Just remove the `i++` statement after `if` statement.